# Android Studio 2.1 Error while Lauching activity - Default Activity not found

Tags: android

El problema en si lo que tengo! Es que al momento de compilar mi aplicación, con el  AVD Manager o incluso con el plugin Genymotion Device Manager, hace todo lo que tiene que hacer pero al momento de lanzar la aplicación o abrirla tira error.
Y no es un proyecto tan grande, solo son de pruebas

```
Fecha (Date): Launching app
No local changes, not deploying APK
Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found
Error while Launching activity
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error "*Default Activity not found*" se dispara cuando no hay una actividad marcada como principal (*MAIN*) en `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Deberías tener una declaración como la siguiente dentro de `<application> </application>`:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.tu.package.NombreDeActividad"
        android:label="@string/nombre_de_la_app">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```